# I installed VisualBoy Advance to do some classic GBA gaming, but I can't find it anywhere

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

Software Center says it's installed, but searching through my entire computer, I can't seem to find it anywhere. I've tried the which command, find, nothing works. all I can find is the .deb file that I downloaded in my downloads folder. if anyone could help, that'd be great.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Did you use the .deb file to install the program?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly you installed it in detail, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the contents of an installed deb file like this :

```
dpkg -L some-GBA-package
```

Or if it creates a lot of output :

```
dpkg -L some-GBA-package | less
```

Or to see the content of your downloaded deb file :

```
dpkg --contents some-GBA-package.deb
```

I just installed it (visualboyadvance-gtk), and found it in my menu entry.
Looking at what it launches it is the command :

```
gvba
```

Try that command in a terminal.